# POSTed values off by one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, formcollection

I am posting a form to an MVC4 controller-action. I am iterating over the `FormCollection` as so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(string nctId, FormCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = Request.Form[key]; // <-- breakpoint here
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { nctId = nctId });
    }
```

I (think I) am submitting a form with the following `select` inputs:

- name="ddlOne", id="ddlOne", value="ValueOne"
- name="ddlTwo", id="ddlTwo", value="ValueTwo"
- name="ddlThree", id="ddlThree", value="ValueThree"

However, when I place a breakpoint on the indicated line, I see the following results:

- key: "ddlOne", value: null
- key: "ddlTwo", value: "ValueOne"
- key: "ddlThree", value: "ValueTwo"

As you can see, the values are "off by one."

What might cause this issue?

Comment: can you show the markup of your `select` list also just as a suggestion use model binding instead of `FormsCollection` iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The break-point happens *before* the assignment occurs.

Press F10 once to advance execution over the assignment and see the updated (and correct) pairing. Alternatively, verify that all is well by inspecting `Request.Form` directly.

Comment: Ah! Of course. It already knows what `key` is but it hasn't assigned `value` yet.

Comment: I guess I didn't think that it would recycle `value` on the next iteration

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos The VS debugger is really good, but there are tiny gremlins here and there. It takes some practice to step around the little critters.